# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a Job Register Table and that table doesn't have any records.

This is my LINQ code:

```
Dim QRecordCount = (From LC In CntxtJobDetails.JobRegistrations _
                            Where LC.JobCode <> 0 _
                            Select LC.JobCode).Max() + 1
```

When I execute the code above it gives me the following error:

> > The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type

Please tell me how can I solve this issue, **I prefer VB.NET Code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure it runs the nullable overload of Max:

```
Dim QRecordCount = (From LC In CntxtJobDetails.JobRegistrations _
                            Where LC.JobCode <> 0 _
                            Select CType(LC.JobCode, Decimal?)).Max() + 1
```

For more information, see this link:
http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/15/applying-aggregates-to-empty-collections-causes-exception-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

And this one:
[Linq query with nullable sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696431/linq-query-with-nullable-sum-problem/2232796#2232796)

Comment: I also found the MSDN topic https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/479f2823-c942-4990-adca-21e03f969a12/sum-on-empty-table-throws-invalidoperationexception?forum=linqprojectgeneral
Even tho Linq works this way by design, I would say it is the wrong design as it doesn't behave as expected, if you Max a decimal and the return type of the funtion is a decimal then you expect a decimal, not a null.
This design has introduced a bug into at least my code, so I would say this is bad design on the part of Linq