# VB.NET LINQ to EF Sum Function Error when no records returned

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

Have seen some solutions for C# but do not know how to solve the issue in VB.NET.

Query:

```
Dim Query = (From t In myEntities.Bookings
Where(t.Ref = Someid)
Select t.People).Sum()
```

`t.Ref` field is an `Int` and so is `t.People`.

The `SomeId` value is the primary key of the related table. This issue is that there will not always be records in the `Bookings` table with a Ref value of Someid - so the query throws the following error.

I have seen others have got around this problem with catching the error, but from reading up on this and as per the error information it seems there should be a solution (in VB.NET) to cast the query or some of the fields in the query to nullable types?

Error is as follows:

`The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

Answer (score 0):

Your Sum() is dealing with ints, and what you really want is a nullable int.

`Dim Query = (From t In myEntities.Bookings Where(t.Ref = Someid) Select t.People).Sum(Function(x) CType(x, Integer?))`

See here: [Linq query with nullable sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696431/linq-query-with-nullable-sum-problem)