# Sum in Linq to Sql not returning a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for a query to return the sum of all payments against an invoice ID - however, if there are no payments noted, the query below returns null.  Is there any way of it returning 0 instead of null?  I've tried adding ?? 0 at the end, but get the message `Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and int`

AmountAllocated is of type Decimal:

```
public decimal AmountAllocated { get; set; }
```

Thanks, Mark

The following returns null for Sum when there are no payment rows found:

```
 var invoiceVM = from i in db.Invoices
         where i.UserName==userName
         select new NewInvoiceViewModel
         {
           InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,
           SumPayments = 
              db.PaymentInvoices.Where(pi => pi.InvoiceId == i.InvoiceId)
                                .Select(pi => pi.AmountAllocated).Sum()
                        };
```

The following results in the `Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and int` error:

```
  var invoiceVM = from i in db.Invoices
         where i.UserName==userName
         select new NewInvoiceViewModel
         {
           InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,
           SumPayments = 
             db.PaymentInvoices.Where(pi => pi.InvoiceId == i.InvoiceId)
                                .Sum(pi => pi.AmountAllocated) ?? 0

                        };
```

If there have been payments made, then AmountAllocated correctly returns the sum of those payments - just it returns null if there are no payment rows found.

You can see from the screenshot below, the first record has a payment, and shows correct as 10 (decimal) - the second record has no payments, and shows as null (decimal).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: to use `??` operator your operand must be `Nullable<T>`, for example `decimal?` or `int?`

Comment: I've deleted my answer for the moment as it feels like there's too much unknown information. a) where did you try using `??` (inside or outside `Sum`)? b) what's the type of `AmountAllocated`? c) when you say "the query below returns null" do you mean that `SumPayments` is null for some rows, or that there are no results? d) Is `AmountAllocated` ever null?

Comment: Hi - I've updated my question to show more clearly what I'm looking for.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: `Sum()` returns a non nullable `int` (or `decimal`), so it will  return a `0` in stead of `null`.

Comment: Hi - it doesn't though - I've updated my question to show a screenshot where it returns a value for the first record, second record shows null.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: I am not sure but `.Sum(pi => pi.AmountAllocated ?? 0)` instead of `.Sum(pi => pi.AmountAllocated) ?? 0` should work.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696431/linq-query-with-nullable-sum

Answer (score 1):

You could try testing to see if there are any rows to be returned.

```
{
       InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,
       SumPayments = 
          db.PaymentInvoices.Any(pi => pi.InvoiceId == i.InvoiceId)
          ? db.PaymentInvoices.Where(pi => pi.InvoiceId == i.InvoiceId)
                              .Select(pi => pi.AmountAllocated).Sum()
          : 0
};
```

Another option is to use SumPayments.GetValueOrDefault(), which will return the value or 0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because in SQL all datatypes are nullable but in C# that's not true. Try forcing the enumeration of your payment invoices before you sum them by using `.ToList()`

```
SumPayments = db.PaymentInvoices.Where(pi => pi.InvoiceId == i.InvoiceId)
                                .Select(pi => pi.AmountAllocated)
                                .ToList()
                                .Sum()
```

**UPDATE**: Try to write the query as a join from Invoices to PaymentInvoices and group by the InvoiceId instead. I think the issue you're running into to is because you're trying to perform the aggregate sum as a sub-query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I added your code exactly as above, but got the error (at runtime, not compile time): {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal] ToList[Decimal](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Decimal])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: Oh I see. It's because the Sum is a sub-select. Maybe if you re-write the query to join the Invoice table to the PaymentInvoices and group by InvoiceId instead of the sub-query.